# In Apache how to do an external redirect to the slashless version of a URL with a subfolder .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

On Apache 2.4 I have an .htaccess (in a subfolder) which rewrites slashless requests inside that folder to appropriate index files:

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1/index.html [L]
```

This works for the *slashless* version exactly as expected. Now I want to redirect the slashed version externally to the slashless version. I tried adding the lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ $1 [R=302,L]
```

However this does not work: The redirect is issued, however it does not go to the slashless URL, but to a URL with a system specific part injected.

So, for a sample URL `http://example.com/path/to/dir/` the redirected URL looks like this `http://example.com/fs9e/username/sub/public/path/to/dir` instead of just `http://example.com/path/to/dir`.

How can I fix this? Many thanks for any pointers!

---

PS: The real case is a little bit more complicated because I do a subdomain-to-folder rewrite in the root .htacces, but I assume this is not relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)/ $1 [R=302,L]
> ```

You are missing the slash prefix (`/`) on the *substitution* string (2nd argument) - to make the substitution root-relative. Or rather, `/subfolder/` (since this `.htaccess` file is located in a subfolder). Since this is a *relative* substitution string (not starting with a slash or scheme+hostname), the directory-prefix<sup>***1**</sup> (which I assume is `/fs9e/username/sub/public/path/`) is added back (by default<sup>***2**</sup>), resulting in a malformed redirect. (This is correct for internal rewrites, but not external redirects.)

It should be like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /subfolder/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Note you were also missing the end-of-string anchor (`$`) on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. (This also negates the need for the preceding *condition* that checks that `REQUEST_URI` ends in a slash.)

Note also that this "redirect" should go before the earlier "rewrite".

---

***1** The directory-prefix is the absolute filesystem path of the location of the .htaccess file.

***2** The alternative is to set a `RewriteBase /subfolder` - but that then affects all relative substitutions. You could also use an environment variable to apply a specific prefix only to some rules.

Comment: This works perfectly! Good to know that I need to make it an absolute substitution. Thanks a lot @MrWhite!